# How to get this value by using For loop in array php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
<?php
    $citySurvey = array("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Rome", "Paris",
    "Paris", "Paris", "London", "Rome", "Rome",
    "Paris", "London", "Paris", "London", "London",
    "London", "Paris", "London", "Paris", "Rome");

    print ("<h1>CITY SURVEY RESULTS</h1>");
    print ("<table border = \"1\">");
    print ("<tr><td>cities</td><td>Counts</td></tr>");


    print ("</table>");
```

?>

I need to use For Loop to get this array code works.
I need to get the number of people who chose each of these cities.

I need to display the result in the table. The first column is the name of cities and second is counts.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are looking for : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Always try to separate HTML from PHP as much as possible.

2.You need to use [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for desired output

Code needs to be like below:-

```
<?php
    $citySurvey = array("London", "Paris", "Rome", "Rome", "Paris",
    "Paris", "Paris", "London", "Rome", "Rome",
    "Paris", "London", "Paris", "London", "London",
    "London", "Paris", "London", "Paris", "Rome");

    $count_city_array = array_count_values($citySurvey);
?>
<h1>CITY SURVEY RESULTS</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>cities</td>
        <td>Counts</td>
    </tr>
<?php

foreach($count_city_array as $key=>$val){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val;?></td>
    </tr>

 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Output on my local screen:- https://prnt.sc/j6u4ay

Comment: The code works! Thanks, I need some explanation for this code. Why can't I use For Loop to find out the value?

Comment: @BoramLamppa  `foreach()` specially made for array iteration and it always take care of indexes itself, that's why always preferable over `for()` loop. You can use `for()` loop also.

Comment: @BoramLamppa  glad to help you :):)